# How would you display each element of an array that is returned from another method in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

For example, I have my main method as well as the method returnOdds(original), that returns the integer array "odd"

How would I print the elements of this array in the main method? With a for loop?

Comment: assign return value to array by calling method then use a for loop

Comment: Use `Arrays.toString()` for the returned array from `returnOdds()` method

Answer (score 3):

A `for` loop would work.  If you don't care about the format, though, a simpler solution might be to use `Arrays.toString`, which will convert in the form `"[elem1, elem2, ..., elemn]"`.

Answer (score 3):

> "With a for loop?"

answer : ***"yes"***